# Show that if $ \forall\bar x \neq 0 \in V$, if $c \neq 0$ then $c*x \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I wrote the following proof, however I am unsure if it is complete because it seems too simple? Any help would be appreciated!

Let $\bar x\in V$ and $c \in \Bbb R$ 
Then $c*\bar x =0$ $iff$ $c=0$ $or$ $\bar x=0$
However, since $c\neq0$ and $\bar x\neq0$ by definition, $c*\bar x\neq0$

Comment: The fact that $cx = 0 \iff c = 0 \lor x = 0$ is basically what you are being asked to prove. I doubt you can use that. Presumably this question wants you to reason from the axioms of a vector space.

Comment: ... and we here do not know what axioms were used in your textbook.

Comment: If $cx = 0$ and $c \neq 0$, then we can multiply by $c^{-1}$ to obtain $c^{-1}(cx) = 0$. The LHS is equal to $(c^{-1}c)x = 1x = x$, so conclude that $x=0$. Here I assume that you have the axioms: $1x = x$ and $a(bx) = (ab)x$ where $a,b$ are scalars. (I also implicitly used that $c^{-1}0 = 0$, which you should justify.)